# Connecting SQL Server using Server IP Address

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connectivity

This works when I try it internally (Within the LAN network)

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
            "Data Source=192.168.1.200,1433;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
              "User Id=MyUserName;" & _
              "Password=MyPassword;"
```

But **this fails** when I try to connect it over internet using server IP address.

```
sConnString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;" & _
            "Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.XX,1433;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=MyDB;" & _
              "User Id=MyUserName;" & _
              "Password=MyPassword;"
```

Any suggestions? The firewall is completely turned off.

Comment: You have local network behind some kind of router with NAT. You need to forward some incoming port in your router to your SQL server machine port 1433. Like other people said, this is not best solution security-wise; you at least need to limit source address range for possible SQL clients somehow (in router firewall rules and then in SQL server firewall rules). BTW, Microsoft is not at fault here.

Comment: Have you actually verified that you can telnet on that IP on port 1433 from this external location? `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1433`.